# Music Player by Python

Tags: python, audio-player

I wrote this music player code and when I hit the next button and then I work with slider the time Elapsed in the status bar resets to zero. and also all music that I play have the same Total lenght.But if I select the music and hit play button the total lenght change.but slider doesnt work properly.The ONLY way all things work correctly is when I hit stop and then select the music and hit play.

```
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import *
import pygame
from pygame import mixer
from tkinter import filedialog
import re
import time
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
from tkinter import ttk as ttk

# initializing the window...............................
window = Tk()
window.minsize(700, 450)
mixer.init()  # initializing the pygame mixer module

# songlist box.............................................................
song_box = Listbox(window, bg="dim gray", fg="black", selectbackground="firebrick",
                   selectforeground="black", width=31, height=10)
song_box.place(x=255, y=78)


# Browse file for Open Menu...........................................................

def browse_files():
    global songs_list
    songs_list = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir="c:/Users/ali/Downloads/Music",
                                             title="Choose Songs", filetypes=(("mp3 File", "*.mp3"),))

    for item in songs_list:
        # getting just the name of song not the whole directory
        pattern = "(.*\/.*\/)(.*)"
        item = re.match(pattern, item).group(2)
        song_box.insert(END, item)

    song_box.select_set(0)


def show_song_time():
    if stopped:
        return
    # Getting the current song Elapsed time in seconds
    current_time = pygame.mixer.music.get_pos() / 1000
    # Convert to time format
    converted_currnet_time = time.strftime("%M:%S", time.gmtime(current_time))

    # Getting what song is playing
    i = song_box.curselection()
    get_active_song = song_box.get(i)
    first_list_item = songs_list[0]
    pattern = "(.*\/.*\/)(.*)"
    directory = re.match(pattern, first_list_item).group(1)
    # directory + the name of the song
    active_song = f"{directory}{get_active_song}"
    if active_song == song:
        # Grab the length with Mutagen
        song_mutagen = MP3(active_song)
        global song_lenght
        song_lenght = song_mutagen.info.length
        # Conver to time format
        global converted_song_length
        converted_song_length = time.strftime("%M:%S", time.gmtime(song_lenght))
        status_bar.config(text=f"Time Elapsed {converted_currnet_time} of {converted_song_length}")
        current_time += 1
        # for end the counting at the end of song
        if int(slider.get()) == int(song_lenght):
            status_bar.config(text=f"Time Elapsed {converted_song_length}")
        elif int(slider.get()) == int(current_time):
            slider_position = int(song_lenght)
            slider.config(to=slider_position, value=int(current_time))
        elif pause_situation:
            pass
        else:
            # Updating the slider position
            slider_position = int(song_lenght)
            slider.config(to=slider_position, value=int(slider.get()))

            # Convert to time format
            converted_currnet_time = time.strftime("%M:%S", time.gmtime(int(slider.get())))
            status_bar.config(text=f"Time Elapsed {converted_currnet_time} of {converted_song_length}")

            next_time = int(slider.get()) + 1
            slider.config(value=next_time)

        # else:
        #     slider_position = int(song_lenght)
        #     slider.config(to=slider_position, value=int(slider.get()))
    else:
        status_bar.config(text=f"Time Elapsed {converted_currnet_time} of {converted_song_length}")

    # making this function running
    # slider.config(value=int(current_time))
    status_bar.after(1000, show_song_time)


# functions..............................................

def play():
    global song
    global song_box
    global song_number_in_list
    global pause_situation
    try:
        global stopped
        stopped = False
        if not pause_situation:
            item = songs_list[0]
            pattern = "(.*\/.*\/)(.*)"
            directory = re.match(pattern, item).group(1)
            # selected song by clicking
            selected_song = song_box.get(ACTIVE)
            # directory + the name of the song
            song = f"{directory}{selected_song}"
            mixer.music.load(song)
            mixer.music.play(loops=0)
            song_number_in_list = song_box.curselection()

            show_song_time()
        else:
            mixer.music.unpause()
            pause_situation = False

    except (pygame.error, NameError) as e:
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Open Error", e)


pause_situation = False
def pause(is_paused):
    global pause_situation
    pause_situation = is_paused
    if pause_situation:
        mixer.music.unpause()
        pause_situation = False
    else:
        mixer.music.pause()
        pause_situation = True


stopped = False
def stop():
    # Reset slider and status bar
    status_bar.config(text="")
    slider.config(value=0)
    # Stop song
    mixer.music.stop()
    song_box.selection_clear(ACTIVE)
    # pause_situation = False
    global stopped
    stopped = True


def next_song():
    try:
        status_bar.config(text="")
        slider.config(value=0)
        next_one = 0
        # Get the current number of the song_box
        next_one = song_box.curselection()
        # Add one to the current song to get the next one number
        next_music = next_one[0] + 1
        # Get the song title from song_box
        song = song_box.get(next_music)
        # Add full directory to song
        i = songs_list[0]
        pattern = "(.*\/.*\/)(.*)"
        directory = re.match(pattern, i).group(1)
        # directory + the name of the song
        song = f"{directory}{song}"
        mixer.music.load(song)
        mixer.music.play(loops=0)

        # Clear Active bar in song_box
        song_box.selection_clear(0, END)

        # Active new song bar
        song_box.activate(next_music)

        # set the acctive bar for next song
        song_box.select_set(next_music, last=None)

        # for stop song when  hit next and then remove it
        global next_song_number
        next_song_number = song_box.curselection()

    except (pygame.error, IndexError):
        pass


def previous_song():
    try:
        status_bar.config(text="")
        slider.config(value=0)
        next_one = 0
        # Get the current number of the song_box
        next_one = song_box.curselection()
        # Add one to the current song to get the next one number
        next_music = next_one[0] - 1
        # Get the song title from song_box
        song = song_box.get(next_music)
        # Add full directory to song
        i = songs_list[0]
        pattern = "(.*\/.*\/)(.*)"
        directory = re.match(pattern, i).group(1)
        # directory + the name of the song
        song = f"{directory}{song}"
        mixer.music.load(song)
        mixer.music.play(loops=0)

        # Clear Active bar in song_box
        song_box.selection_clear(0, END)

        # Active new song bar
        song_box.activate(next_music)

        # set the acctive bar for next song
        song_box.select_set(next_music, last=None)

        # for stop song when  hit next and then remove it
        global next_song_number
        next_song_number = song_box.curselection()

    except (pygame.error, IndexError):
        pass



# Create Status Bar......................................................
status_bar = Label(window, text="", bd=1, relief=GROOVE, anchor=E)
status_bar.pack(fill=X, side=BOTTOM, pady=2)


# Slide function................................................................
def slide(X):
    try:
        mixer.music.load(song)
        mixer.music.play(loops=0, start=int(slider.get()))
    except NameError as e:
        tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error", e)


# Creating a slider..............................................................
slider = ttk.Scale(window, from_=0, to=100, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=375, value=0, command=slide)
slider.place(x=160, y=320)


# Buttons......................................................................................
play_button = Button(window, text="play", command=play)
play_button.place(x=200, y=250)

pause_button = Button(window, text="pause", command=lambda: pause(pause_situation))
pause_button.place(x=250, y=250)

stop_button = Button(window, text="stop", command=stop)
stop_button.place(x=300, y=250)

next_button = Button(window, text="next", command=next_song)
next_button.place(x=300, y=250)

previous_button = Button(window, text="previous", command=previous_song)
previous_button.place(x=350, y=250)

open_button = Button(window, text="open", command=browse_files)
open_button.place(x=430, y=250)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is a bit too much code. You need to create a [mcve]. It would also be beneficial if you clarified what _"can not work with the slider properly"_ means.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks  @TedKleinBergman you are right I will try to do that.